# Casting Javascript Multidimensional Array to ASMX method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to pass a multi-layered array in the form:

```
array[<string>, array[<string>, <string>]]
```

using jquery ajax

```
var cssarray = [];

function SaveChanges(element, updates) {

        var exists = false;
        var updated = false;

        //need to check if already present and if so overwrite the changes.
        for (var i = 0; i < cssarray.length; i++) {

            if (cssarray[i][0] === element) {
                exists = true;

                var existingupdates = cssarray[i][1];

                for (var j = 0; j < updates.length; j++) {

                    for (var k = 0; k < existingupdates.length; k++) {

                        if (existingupdates[k][0] === updates[j][0]) {
                            existingupdates[k][1] = updates[j][1];
                            updated = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!updated)
                       existingupdates.push(updates[j]); 
                }

                cssarray[i][1] = existingupdates;
            }
        }

        if(!exists)
            cssarray.push([element, updates]);
    }


runAjax('/Public/AdminServices.asmx/UpdateCSS', 'updates', cssarray)
        .done(
            function (__exists) {

                if (__exists.d) {
                    alert(__exists.d);
                }
                else {
                    alert("hmmm error");
                    alert(__exists.d);
                }
            }
        )
        .fail(
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown + ':' + textStatus + ':' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        );

function runAjax(webmethod, fieldname, fieldtext) {

    var jsonObject = {};
    jsonObject[fieldname] = fieldtext;

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webmethod,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

I want to pass it across to my asmx method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[SoapHeader("authentication")]
public string UpdateCSS(string updates)
{

    //add is master check so only admin will be able to change the website
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["IsMaster"])))
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>> css = json.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>>>(updates);
       AdminFunctions.UpdateStyleSheet(css);
        return "User is a valid user";
    }
    else
    {
        return "changes not committed as the user is not authenticated.";
    }
}
```

But it is throwing an unable to cast error on this object? the error being thrown is as follows;

> "Type "System.String" is not supported for deserialization
>   of an array.","StackTrace":"   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList
>   list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean
>   throwOnError, IList\u0026 convertedList)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.StrongTypeParameters(IDictionary`2
>   rawParams)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}

any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Dictionary> I did something similar not so long ago. Or try a nested NameValueCollection

Change

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>> css = json.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>>>(updates);
```

to

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> css = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>>(updates);
```

Comment: Matt, thats fine but the issue is casting it on the server side thats throwing the error. I have tried 
`JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>> css = json.Deserialize<List<KeyValuePair<String, List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>>>>(updates);` bit this too thrown an error when casting?

Would you be able to provide a copy of the working code you used when casting it?

Comment: You need to update your question with the exception you're getting

Answer (score 0):

ok the issue was that I neede to stringify the sub array so the following code fixed the issue script side.

JSON.stringify({ updates: JSON.stringify(fieldtext) })